# Doxygen, Treeview, and TagFiles - Don't Show Other Projects' Pages

Tags: doxygen

I have a Doxygen project which references the tagfile of another project.

I set Doxygen to show a treeview on the left. However, the final html output shows not only the pages in my project, but also the pages in the other project - and it makes no distinction between them (i.e. a section title?).

I want to have my project reference the other project and want to have links in my pages link to the other project (which works), but I don't want to see several "Welcome" pages and "Building Instructions" pages in the sidebar of all my projects with no way to know which is which.

How do I:

- Not put referenced-projects' pages in the sidebar, but keep them referencable via links; or
- Have it put a section header telling which project the pages come from?

Comment: Which version of doxygen?

Comment: Both 1.8.4 and 1.8.14

Comment: Please create a MWE to show the problem (waiting on a MWE of an older question as well).

Comment: Ok, I take it back, this problem only happens in 1.8.4, not 1.8.14... It doesn't list all the files in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in newer versions of Doxygen, though I cannot test enough to find *which* version fixes this issue.

Comment: If you provide a MWE I could have a look, but it is in my opinion not worth the effort.